# Dillema with buffer overflow

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

I'm playing with one stack overflow example. This example looks like this:

```
 void return_input (void){ 
    char array[30];    
    gets (array); 
    printf("%s\n", array); 

 }

 main() { 
    return_input();    
    return 0;    
 }
```

All this code is in the file called overflow.c. We have vulnerable function called **return_input**, particularly it's 30 byte char array. I compiled it and opened vulnerable function in **gdb** and got following output:

```
 (gdb) disas return_input
 0x08048464 <+0>:   push   %ebp
 0x08048465 <+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
 0x08048467 <+3>:   sub    $0x48,%esp
 0x0804846a <+6>:   mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 0x08048470 <+12>:  mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
 0x08048473 <+15>:  xor    %eax,%eax
 0x08048475 <+17>:  lea    -0x2a(%ebp),%eax
 0x08048478 <+20>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
 0x0804847b <+23>:  call   0x8048360 <gets@plt>
 0x08048480 <+28>:  lea    -0x2a(%ebp),%eax
 0x08048483 <+31>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
 0x08048486 <+34>:  call   0x8048380 <puts@plt>
 0x0804848b <+39>:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 0x0804848e <+42>:  xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
 0x08048495 <+49>:  je     0x804849c <return_input+56>
 0x08048497 <+51>:  call   0x8048370 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 0x0804849c <+56>:  leave  
 0x0804849d <+57>:  ret    
 End of assembler dump.
```

As you see from the function prologue we reserved hex48(dec 72) bytes on the stack for local variables. First I was trying to find the address where our vulnerable array starts on the stack. I think it's -0x2a(%ebp), am I right? Hex2a is 42 decimal. As I understand it means that we can write safely 42 bytes before we start to overwrite EBP saved on the stack. But when I run this example it's enough to right only 37 bytes to get segmentation fault:

```
rustam@rustam-laptop:~/temp/ELF_reader$ ./overflow
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How is 37 bytes enough to overflow buffer? If our local char array is -42 bytes from saved EBP

Comment: Unrelated, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249315/what-is-gs-in-assembly) is *extremely* similar.

Comment: In C, writing 31 bytes to a 30-byte array is enough to overflow that array (and cause Undefined Behaviour).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing the whole disassembly of the function.

However, my guess is that the %gs:0x14 stored at -0xc(%ebp) may be your [stack canary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries) that causes a clean exit if a stack coruption is detected.
So this value is stored at -0xc(%ebp), which means that your buffer is in fact only 30 bytes large, followed by whatever comes after.

Comment: Thanks dude, recompiled without gcc stack protection, and assembly code gives all values correctly.